# Difference between "command > log.txt" and "command 1>& log.txt" in Linux command shell?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

When I run the command `haizea -c simulated.conf > result.txt`, the program (`haizea`) still prints its output to the screen. But when I try `haizea -c simulated.conf 1>& result.txt`, the output is now on the file `result.txt`. I'm quite confused about this situation. What is the difference between `>` and `1>&`, then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing on the terminal is the standard *error* of your process. Both of these are directed to the same terminal device by default (assuming no redirection put into effect).

The redirection `>&xyz` redirects both standard output *and* error to the file `xyz`.

I've never used it but I would think, by extension, that `N>&xyz` would redirect file handle `N` and standard error to your file. So `1>&xyz` is equivalent to `>&xyz` which is also equivalent to `>xyz 2>&1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a great answer. After reading it I came up with the command `haizea -c simulated.conf 2>&1 | grep 'CLOCK'`, which I'd really wanted.

Comment: I do not know why, but I always use and prefer >xyz 2>&1

Answer (score 2):

The number before the `>` stands for the descriptor.

```
Standard Input - 0
Standard Output - 1
Standard Error - 2
```

The `&` will direct both standard output and standard error.

http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/lpt/13_01.html#doc2ac15b1c13

Answer (score 1):

`>` redirects standard output alone.

`>&` or `&>` or `1>&` redirect **both** standard output and standard error.

Your program is printing on standard error which is not getting redirected in case 1.